# is it possible to unlike a comment via facebook's graph API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with the facebook graph api to display a user's feed and comments.

I'm able to like and unlike posts just fine, using the same code (obviously with a comment ID instead of the post id) I'm able to like the comment it works fine, but when I try to unlike the comment I get back "NetworkError: 500 OK - https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX_YYYY/likes?access_token=my-access-token-is-here" and the content is a Json object with the properties of:

```
readyState      0
responseText    ""
status          0
statusText      "error"
```

my unlike function which works fine when sent a post id:

```
function UnLike(el, id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/likes?access_token=' + AuthToken,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(data) {
            $(el).off('click').on('click', Like).html('Like');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

el is the link that was clicked to "Unlike", id is the object id sent from facebook for the post/comment/etc.

the ID being sent is correct, I've verified that through firebug, its the feed_data.comments.data[index-of-comment].id value that's returned by the graph api.  The exact same id is being used to Like comments and that's working fine.

Comment: A `DELETE` on `POSTID_COMMENTID/likes` works fine for me to UNLIKE a comment. Can you try in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)?

Comment: It started working for me a few days after I posted this, no change to my code at all, just started working.